# Renaming all file extensions with Python

Tags: python

So I have a group of folders with many subfolders in them, and each of those have subfolders have multiple .pyc files and .pyc.py inside them. I have made a script on deleting all of a certain extension. Now I'm trying to rename the extensions of the .pyc.py with this code:

```
import os


extensions = ('.py',)

print 'Changing to root directory...'
os.chdir('../')
print 'Current Directory:'
print os.getcwd()
os.chdir('TTOLD')
print "Current Directory:"
print os.getcwd()


def rename(filepath):
    print "Renaming '%s'..." % filepath
    os.rename(filepath, extension)


for root, folders, files in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
        extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
        if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] in extensions:
            rename(filepath)

print 'Finished'
```

This code isn't finished, and I don't exactly know how to finish it. Could anyone help?

Comment: If this is just an excercise to learn python, ignore this comment... but this could be much easier done with something like `find` and `xargs`.

Comment: They might be on Windows though!

Comment: Or use the rename commmand under Linux (if they don't want to use find/xargs and pipes :) http://www.tecmint.com/rename-multiple-files-in-linux/ (again, assuming this is not just a Python exercise, and they have access to a Linux system)